# SignalR messages not received in client when called via Azure WebRole Run() function

Tags: c#, azure, signalr

I'm trying to send a message via SignalR from my WebRole to the client but it's not appearing. It appears fine when I test call it from a Controller, but when called from the Run() function, it doesn't seem to make it over to the client.

```
public override void Run()
{
   processingQueueClient.OnMessage((message) =>
   {
      message.Complete();

      MainHub.Send("Test 1");
   });

   completedEvent.WaitOne();
}


namespace MainWebRole
{
    public class MainHub : Hub
    {
        public static void Send(string message)
        {
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MainHub>();
            context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);
        }
    }
}

<script>
$(function () {
            var chat = $.connection.mainHub;
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {

                var notificationText = "<div><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" onclick=\"onClickClearComplete()\">Clear Complete</button></div><div class=\"spacer10\"></div><div><table class=\"table table-bordered\">";
                notificationText += "<tr><td nowrap><span><i class=\"fa fa-pause\"></i>&nbsp;Pending \"" + message + "\"</span></td></tr>";
                notificationText += "</table></div>";
                $("#statusText").html(notificationText);
            };

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Who sets completed event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to run your signalR send function via below steps:

1) `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client`

2) write below code in Azure web role in run function.

```html
HubConnection _hub = new HubConnection("http://localhost:1942");
var _proxy = _hub.CreateHubProxy("MainHub");
if (_hub.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
{
      await _hub.Start();
}
await _proxy.Invoke("Send", "jambor");
```

`http://localhost:1942` is your SignalR server site.

`MainHub` is your SignalR hub class name

`Send` is your function in MainHub class.